# CSS 'overflow-wrap' does not work in React.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, overflow, word-wrap

I want to be able to handle user provided text with newlines and simultaneously text which may be wider than the width of parent elements. By wider than the parent element, I mean something like a single word or line longer than the screen.

I have added `'white-space': 'pre-wrap'` as well as `'overflow-wrap': 'break-word'`. The `white-space` handles newlines, but `overflow-wrap` does not break long words/lines. I've also tried `'word-wrap': 'break-word'` with no luck.

This is all in React.js. Outside of React.js I would just wrap it in a `<pre>`.

Ex:

```
<div class="request-top" style={{'white-space': 'pre-wrap', 'overflow-wrap': 'break-word'}}>
   <p>{text}</p>
</div>
```

I've also tried converting the text variable to a string literal:

```
<p>{`${text}`}</p>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In React, inline style should be camelCased.

The React document [style](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) section also mention:

> The style attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased properties rather than a CSS string.

Try to modify as following:

```js
<div class="request-top" style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap', overflowWrap: 'break-word'}}>
   <p>{text}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, it cannot get simpler than that.